# how to set height of UILabel based on the text we have

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, cgrectmake

I have UILabel of width 260 where I have long text (maybe around 1000 characters).

I wanted to set the height of the UILabel based on the content. Sometimes I can have 100 chars, sometimes I can have 1000 chars).

Based on text, how can I set the height of the UILabel?

**Note:** I am creating UILabel programmatically.

```
 UILabel myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (30,50,260, height)];
```

Any idea how to get this done?

**One way I am trying is as below.**

I am considering there are 40 chars in one line. So what I am doing is finding length of text and divide it by 40. This will give me total number of lines I required.

But this fails when there are new lines.

Is this right way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use:

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * mytext = @"My string";
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:15];
CGSize sz = [mytext sizeWithFont:myLabel.font];
float height = sz.height;
float totalHeight = height*myLabel.numberOfLines;
```

Note that sizeWithFont is [deprecated in iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW6).

Comment: if its deprecated why you are giving this solution?

Comment: Because you haven't specified which OS you use. Also, I gave link for you to figure out what you can use instead of sizeWithFont. Isn't that the objective of such forum?